# NodeJS routes with or without file extensions

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

With the following route:

```
app.get('/', controller.web.Home);
```

How would I add within `'/'` something which would allow a match for `/`, `/index` and `/index.html`? I would also like to use this approach for all other routes so that users don't see an error page when adding .html to a path.

I have seen this mentioned on the Express website, however there are no clear explanations for matching multiples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Express uses [path-to-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) for routing strings meaning you can use regular expressions or string patterns to match routes.

> How would I add within '/' something which would allow a match for /, /index and /index.html

Something like this would work:

```
app.get('/|index|index.html', controller.web.Home);
```

> I would also like to use this approach for all other routes so that users don't see an error page when adding .html to a path.

You can also write a small helper function that takes care of this for any route:

```
function htmlExt(route) {
  return route + '|' + route + '.html';
}
```

And the use it for any route:

```
app.get(htmlExt('index'), controller.web.Home);
app.get(htmlExt('blog'), controller.web.Blog);
// ...
```

---

#### Other approaches

You can also pass in an array of paths instead so this should also work:

```
function htmlExt(route) {
  return [route, route + '.html'];
}
app.get(htmlExt('index'), controller.web.Home);
```

Another way would be to use a regex. Perhaps one that accepts a route and an optional `.html` extension:

```
app.get(/index(.html)?/, controller.web.Home);
```

You can find other useful examples in [Express Routing docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Comment: What is this: `'/|index|index.html'`?  It looks like half string, half regex?

Comment: Express uses [path-to-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) under the hood which allows passing in string patterns instead of regexes

Comment: Thanks for that, the helper function will be useful for future reference :)

Answer (score 3):

You can define an array of paths as the first argument:

```
app.get(['/', '/index' , '/index.html'], controller.web.Home);
```

Comment: please fix 'index.html' to '/index.html'

Comment: @simone.sanfratello Fixed. Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

using express 4.x

```
app.get('/(index*)?', controller.web.Home);
```

reference
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global approach you can use a middleware function. Put it before all of your routes.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var match = req.path.match(/(.*)\.html$/)
    if (match !== null) {
        res.redirect(match[1]);
    } else {
        next();    
    }
});
```

It redirects every path ending with .html to a route without this extension.
Of course the route path '/' needs to be handled separately.